# "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" when running kubelet

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, kubelet

I'm trying to install kubernetes with kubelet 1.4.5 on CoreOS beta (1192.2.0).

I'm using a slightly modified version of the controller and worker install scripts from https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/tree/master/multi-node/generic

so in general I created the licenses on Gentoo Linux using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MASTER_HOST=coreos-2.tux-in.com
export K8S_SERVICE_IP=10.3.0.1
export WORKER_IP=10.79.218.3
export WORKER_FQDN=coreos-3.tux-in.com
openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca-key.pem -days 10000 -out ca.pem -subj "/CN=kube-ca"
openssl genrsa -out apiserver-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key apiserver-key.pem -out apiserver.csr -subj "/CN=kube-apiserver" -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -in apiserver.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out apiserver.pem -days 365 -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cnf
openssl genrsa -out ${WORKER_FQDN}-worker-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key ${WORKER_FQDN}-worker-key.pem -out ${WORKER_FQDN}-worker.csr -subj "/CN=${WORKER_FQDN}" -config worker-openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -in ${WORKER_FQDN}-worker.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out ${WORKER_FQDN}-worker.pem -days 365 -extensions v3_req -extfile worker-openssl.cnf
openssl genrsa -out admin-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key admin-key.pem -out admin.csr -subj "/CN=kube-admin"
openssl x509 -req -in admin.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out admin.pem -days 365
echo done
```

and this is `openssl.cnf`

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = coreos-2.tux-in.com
DNS.2 = coreos-3.tux-in.com
IP.1 = 10.3.0.1
IP.2 = 10.79.218.2
IP.3 = 10.79.218.3
```

and this is my `worker-openssl.cnf`

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 10.79.218.3
DNS.1 = coreos-3.tux-in.com
```

My controller machine is `coreos-2.tux-in.com` which resolves to the lan ip `10.79.218.2`

my worker machine is `coreos-3.tux-in.com` which resolves to lan ip `10.79.218.3`

it created the licenses just fine. but when I use them and install the controller script on the main machine, i see that when I run `journalctl -xef -u kubelet` and I noticed the following messages:

```
Nov 08 21:24:06 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:06.805868    2018 event.go:208] Unable to write event: 'x509: certificate signed by unknown authority' (may retry after sleeping)
Nov 08 21:24:06 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:06.950827    2018 reflector.go:203] pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:384: Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Nov 08 21:24:07 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:07.461042    2018 reflector.go:203] pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:43: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D10.79.218.2&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Nov 08 21:24:07 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:07.461340    2018 reflector.go:203] pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:403: Failed to list *api.Node: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D10.79.218.2&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Nov 08 21:24:08 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:08.024366    2018 reflector.go:203] pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:384: Failed to list *api.Service: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Nov 08 21:24:08 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:08.171170    2018 eviction_manager.go:162] eviction manager: unexpected err: failed GetNode: node '10.79.218.2' not found
Nov 08 21:24:08 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:08.543619    2018 reflector.go:203] pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:403: Failed to list *api.Node: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D10.79.218.2&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Nov 08 21:24:08 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[2018]: E1108 21:24:08.543926    2018 reflector.go:203] pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:43: Failed to list *api.Pod: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D10.79.218.2&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: Could you also take a look into the logs of the other Kubernetes components? Especially of the master apiserver. If I see it correctly you should be able to see the components with `docker ps` and display them with `docker logs <containerid>`.

Comment: Using rocket. And I don't have specific logs per container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general the solution was to create another etcd2 port that attaches to loopback device of each machine and works on `http` instead of `https`. more information at [calico-policy-controller requests etcd2 certificates of a different coreos server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233096/calico-policy-controller-requests-etcd2-certificates-of-a-different-coreos-serve)

Answer (score 2):

The kubelet [documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/) says that the `--tls-cert-file` flag needs the CA be concatenated after the certificate. In you case it is the `apiserver.pem`:

> **--tls-cert-file** File containing x509 Certificate for HTTPS.  (CA cert, if any, concatenated after server cert). If --tls-cert-file and --tls-private-key-file are not provided, a self-signed certificate and key are generated for the public address and saved to the directory passed to --cert-dir.

If I read you certificate generation correctly, the `apiserver.pem` doesn't contain the root ca.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i appended the ca to the apiserver.pem file but the results are exactly the same.

Comment: what do you mean by append?

Answer (score 1):

```
0. if your issue is :
: Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: invalid signature: parent certificate cannot sign this kind of certificate"

1. look at your ca.crt 
openssl x509  -noout -text -in ca.crt, you will find below info :

 X509v3 Basic Constraints:
  CA:FLASE

X509v3 Basic Constraints means :
"Basic Constraints" identifies if the subject of certificates is a CA who is allowed to issue child certificates. For a certificate that can be used to sign certificates, the info is in some sense duplicated: X509v3 Basic Constraints: CA: TRUE --- Can sign certificates.

you should modify it to CA:TRUE through vi openssl.conf
[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints = CA:true

Regenerate your crts.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kubelet with rkt on CoreOS 1192.2.0.

This is the unit i use to start kubelet on the worker:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubelet via Hyperkube ACI
Requires=k8s-assets.target
After=k8s-assets.target
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/proxy.env
Environment="RKT_OPTS=--volume=resolv,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf --mount volume=resolv,target=/etc/resolv.conf --volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log"
Environment=KUBELET_VERSION=v1.4.0_coreos.0
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
--api-servers=https://10.203.69.108 \
--register-node=true \
--allow-privileged=true \
--config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests    \
--hostname-override=node2.my.domain  \
--cluster_dns=10.3.0.10 \
--cluster_domain=cluster.local \
--kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml \
--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/worker.pem \
--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/worker-key.pem
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What is important is

**--api-servers** that must point to the **IP** address of the master

**--tls-cert-file** that must point to the worker certificate public key

**--tls-private-key-file** that must point to the worker certificate private key

**--kubeconfig** that must point to a valid kubeconfig file

Here my kubeconfig file (it contain the path to the CA that have signed the certificates):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: local
  cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
users:
- name: kubelet
  user:
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/worker.pem
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/worker-key.pem
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: local
    user: kubelet
  name: kubelet-context
current-context: kubelet-context
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your answer. i closed the worker server and I still get the same error messages. it means that it doesn't really relate to the worker configuration no ?

Comment: I think you have invert the worker/master dns name and the worker/master ip. You have written that the worker is coreos-3.tux-in.com with ip 10.79.218.3 (in the bash script to generate the certificates) but after you have written: "my worker machine is coreos-2.tux-in.com which resolves to lan ip 10.79.218.3"

Answer (score 0):

Your OpenSSL certificates are "self-signed":

```
openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca-key.pem -days 10000 -out ca.pem -subj "/CN=kube-ca"
```

That is to say, you are signing them instead of a trusted [certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).  It should be completely fine and safe, as long as you keep the private keys safe.

If you want it to be signed by a certificate authority, you will need to generate a CSR (certificate signing request).

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs

Comment: hi. thanks for your answer. so the problem is that they're self signed? if i want to keep using self signed certificates, what do i do? how do i get rid of this error ?