# calico-policy-controller requests etcd2 certificates of a different coreos server

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, etcd2

i have two coreos stable servers,

each one includes an etcd2 server and they share the same discovery url.

each generated a different certificate for each of the etcd2 daemons. i installed kubernetes controller on one, (`coreos-2.tux-in.com`) and a worker on `coreos-3.tux-in.com`.  calico is configured to use the etcd2 certificates for `coreos-2.tux-in.com`,

but it seems that kuberenetes started the calico-policy-controller on `coreos-3.tux-in.com` so it can't find the etcd2 certificates. `coreos-2.tux-in.com` certificates file names start with `etcd1` and `coreos-3.tux-in.com` certificates start with `etcd2`.

so.. do i just place certificates for both etcd2 daemons on both coreos servers? do I need to restrict `kube-policy-controller` to start on `coreos-2.tux-in.com`? what do i do here?

this is my `/srv/kubernetes/manifests/calico.yaml` file.

```
# This ConfigMap is used to configure a self-hosted Calico installation.
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: calico-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  # Configure this with the location of your etcd cluster.
  etcd_endpoints: "https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379,https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379"
  etcd_ca: "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
  etcd_key: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
  etcd_cert: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"

  # The CNI network configuration to install on each node.  The special
  # values in this config will be automatically populated.
  cni_network_config: |-
    {
        "name": "calico",
        "type": "flannel",
        "delegate": {
          "type": "calico",
          "etcd_endpoints": "__ETCD_ENDPOINTS__",
          "etcd_ca": "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
          "etcd_key": "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
          "etcd_cert": "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
          "log_level": "info",
          "policy": {
              "type": "k8s",
              "k8s_api_root": "https://__KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST__:__KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT__",
              "k8s_auth_token": "__SERVICEACCOUNT_TOKEN__"
          },
          "kubernetes": {
              "kubeconfig": "/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d/__KUBECONFIG_FILENAME__"
          }
        }
    }

---

# This manifest installs the calico/node container, as well
# as the Calico CNI plugins and network config on
# each master and worker node in a Kubernetes cluster.
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: calico-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-node
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations: |
          [{"key": "dedicated", "value": "master", "effect": "NoSchedule" },
           {"key":"CriticalAddonsOnly", "operator":"Exists"}]
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
        # Runs calico/node container on each Kubernetes node.  This
        # container programs network policy and routes on each
        # host.
        - name: calico-node
          image: quay.io/calico/node:v1.0.0
          env:
            # The location of the Calico etcd cluster.
            - name: ETCD_ENDPOINTS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: etcd_endpoints
            # Choose the backend to use.
            - name: ETCD_CA_CERT_FILE
              value: "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
            - name: ETCD_CERT_FILE
              value: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
            - name: ETCD_KEY_FILE
              value: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
            - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
              value: "none"
            # Disable file logging so 'kubectl logs' works.
            - name: CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING
              value: "true"
            - name: NO_DEFAULT_POOLS
              value: "true"
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /lib/modules
              name: lib-modules
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /var/run/calico
              name: var-run-calico
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /etc/resolv.conf
              name: dns
              readOnly: true
        # This container installs the Calico CNI binaries
        # and CNI network config file on each node.
        - name: install-cni
          image: quay.io/calico/cni:v1.5.2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["/install-cni.sh"]
          env:
            # CNI configuration filename
            - name: CNI_CONF_NAME
              value: "10-calico.conf"
            # The location of the Calico etcd cluster.
            - name: ETCD_ENDPOINTS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: etcd_endpoints
            # The CNI network config to install on each node.
            - name: CNI_NETWORK_CONFIG
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: cni_network_config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /host/opt/cni/bin
              name: cni-bin-dir
            - mountPath: /host/etc/cni/net.d
              name: cni-net-dir
      volumes:
        # Used by calico/node.
        - name: lib-modules
          hostPath:
            path: /lib/modules
        - name: var-run-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/calico
        # Used to install CNI.
        - name: cni-bin-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /opt/cni/bin
        - name: cni-net-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d
        - name: dns
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/resolv.conf

---

# This manifest deploys the Calico policy controller on Kubernetes.
# See https://github.com/projectcalico/k8s-policy
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: calico-policy-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: calico-policy
spec:
  # The policy controller can only have a single active instance.
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: calico-policy-controller
      namespace: kube-system
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-policy
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations: |
          [{"key": "dedicated", "value": "master", "effect": "NoSchedule" },
           {"key":"CriticalAddonsOnly", "operator":"Exists"}]
    spec:
      # The policy controller must run in the host network namespace so that
      # it isn't governed by policy that would prevent it from working.
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
        - name: calico-policy-controller
          image: calico/kube-policy-controller:v0.4.0
          env:
            # The location of the Calico etcd cluster.
            - name: ETCD_ENDPOINTS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: etcd_endpoints
            # The location of the Kubernetes API.  Use the default Kubernetes
            # service for API access.
            - name: ETCD_CA_CERT_FILE
              value: "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
            - name: ETCD_CERT_FILE
              value: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
            - name: ETCD_KEY_FILE
              value: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
            - name: K8S_API
              value: "https://kubernetes.default:443"
            # Since we're running in the host namespace and might not have KubeDNS
            # access, configure the container's /etc/hosts to resolve
            # kubernetes.default to the correct service clusterIP.
            - name: CONFIGURE_ETC_HOSTS
              value: "true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. so my setup at home is 2 pcs with coreos installed on them for testing. so in my scenario i have 2 etcd2 servers, one on each server.

in general kubernetes is for a large scale of servers and they recommend not to have etcd2 servers and kubernetes containers on same machine, since in my case I must have them both in the same server, I opened etcd2 to loopback device `127.0.0.1` on port `4001` with `http` protocol. so now whenever I need to configure etcd2 servers in kubernetes containers, i just point to `http:/127.0.0.1:4001`, and then it points to the etcd2 on that same server without requesting ssl certificates. so services in that same server won't need https for etcd2, but services outside the server will need.